# unknown brackets giving a missing argument response

Tags: discord, discord.js

Trying to make the bot delete messages and send an error message when it's unable to so it doesn't crash trying to delete messages older than 14 days.
Sorry if it's a stupid mistake, I'm fairly new to discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: "clear",
    description: "clear messages",
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"])) {
            if (!args[0])
                return message.reply(
                    "You must specify the number of messages you wish to clear"
                );
            if (isNaN(args[0]))
                return message.reply(
                    "You must provide a valid number of messages you wish to clear"
                );

            if (args[0] > 99)
                return message.reply("You cannot clear over 100 messages");
            if (args[0] < 1)
                return message.reply("You must clear at least one message");

            await message.channel.messages
                .fetch({ limit: parseInt(args[0]) + 1 })
                .then((messages) => {
                    message.channel
                        .bulkDelete(parseInt(args[o]) + 1)
                        .then(() => {
                            message.channel.send(`Cleared ${args[0]} messages`);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            return message.reply("An error occured");
                        });
                });
        } else {
            message.reply("You do not have the permission to do that");
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, just a couple missing brackets here and there.

I would recommend the [bracket pair colorizer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) if you code in vscode it highlights unmatched and missing brackets for you.

**Your code:**

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "clear",
    description: "clear messages",
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"])) {
            if (!args[0])
                return message.reply(
                    "You must specify the number of messages you wish to clear"
                );
            if (isNaN(args[0]))
                return message.reply(
                    "You must provide a valid number of messages you wish to clear"
                );

            if (args[0] > 99)
                return message.reply("You cannot clear over 100 messages");
            if (args[0] < 1)
                return message.reply("You must clear at least one message");

            await message.channel.messages
                .fetch({ limit: parseInt(args[0]) + 1 })
                .then((messages) => {
                    message.channel
                        .bulkDelete(parseInt(args[o]) + 1)
                        .then(() => {
                            message.channel.send(`Cleared ${args[0]} messages`);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            return message.reply("An error occured");
                        });
                });
        } else {
            message.reply("You do not have the permission to do that");
        }
    },
};
```